# Rails: If my Quiz model should be created on completing the quiz, how does form_for know what to refer to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formbuilder

I've been told that I should not create my Quiz object before my quiz is completed; A user could go to the quiz page, not complete it, and there would be an 'unused' quiz sitting on the database. I can see the logic of that.

I CAN'T see how my quiz is supposed to work without being passed a @quiz object. Here's my QuizzesController, which, when the quiz is needed, gets routed to the 'new' action:

```
class QuizzesController < ApplicationController
        def index

        end

        def new
            @user = current_user
            @quiz = Quiz.create(user_id: current_user.id)

        end

        def create
            @results = Quiz.where(user_id: current_user.id).last
            redirect_to results_path
        end
end
```

At the moment, you can see that I'm coding the actions as simply as possible. Later, in the 'new' action, I'll add a test to see if the current_user has done the quiz and, if so, redirect to results_path.

Here is my form partial which is rendered as part of quizzes/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@quiz) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer1) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer2) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer3) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer4) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer5) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer6) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer7) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer8) %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit("Get my results!") %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Once again, the quiz is very simple while I figure out what's going on.

But I'd like to know, if the @quiz object is not created in the 'new' action, what would I pass into `form_for` to build the form?

Comment: in `new` action you build a new record, not yet saved, `Quiz.new ..`; in `create` action you create action `Quiz.create ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate a `Quiz` object without saving it to the database:

```
def new
  @user = current_user
  @quiz = Quiz.new(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

Comment: Ah ha! That makes sense. Then, in the 'create' action, I use params to save it! I'll try that now...

Comment: OK, it's not throwing any errors, but it's also NOT updating the newly created Quiz with a user's answers. Probably something to do with what I'm doing with params, but that's probably yet another question...

Comment: Your create controller method should be calling Quiz.create with the parameters. If you're using Rails 4, you'll need to whitelist any parameters you want to use in mass assignment: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: I'm using `@results = Quiz.create(post_params)` and then the post_params method has the following line...

Comment: post_params line is: `params.require(:quiz).permit(:id, :user_id, :answer1, :answer2, :answer3, :answer4, :answer5, :answer6, :answer7, :answer8)`. Shouldn't that work?

Comment: Your Quiz model has boolean fields :answer1, :answer2, etc.? Off the top of my head that looks like it _should_ work. Does your model have validation rules that might be failing?

Comment: The sole line in the Quiz model is `belongs_to :user`

Comment: I've got it registering the answer1, answer2 attributes now, but NOT user_id - even though that's including in the 'whilelisting'. At least I'm assuming that the post_params method is doing the whitelisting you refer to.

Answer (score 0):

The generally used sequence of requests/actions is the following:

1. The `new` action just initializes the model's instance with default values, and renders the record with empty fields, usually in a `edit` view.

   ```
   def new
      @quiz = Quiz.new(user_id: current_user.id)
      render :edit
   end
   ```
2. `create` action create the record, and after the `create` action you should render either the `view` of the newly created record by redirection to `show` action with the same view, or to redirect to a `new` action, in case you are creating a sequence of the same instances of a model.

   ```
   def create
      @quiz = Quiz.create(params)
      render :show # or redirect_to :new
   end
   ```
3. `edit` action is to prepare edit fields, is it renders `edit` view with filled-in fields.

   ```
   def edit
      @quiz = Quiz.where(id: params[:id]).first
   end
   ```
4. `update` action updates the record with values set in `edit` view, then it renders the `show` view on the current record.

   ```
   def update
      @quiz = Quiz.update(params)
      render :show
   end
   ```
5. `show` action just shows the model's found out with stored in the DB values, then it renders `show` view with filled-in fields.

   ```
   def show
      @quiz = Quiz.where(id: params[:id]).first
   end
   ```

So in your **show.erb** view you get rendering the newly built, or found out instance of `Quiz`:

```
<%= form_for @quiz, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer1) %>
    <%# ... %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Create Quiz" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

But I prefer [simple-form](/questions/tagged/simple-form) gem:

```
<%= simple_form_for @quiz do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :answer1, as: :boolean, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false %>
   <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I hope it's OK to ask, but what user interaction would cause the 'show' action to be triggered? I've been told clicking 'submit' on my form will trigger the 'create' action...

Comment: Sorry - I can't seem to follow your explanation. It looks like you're saying 'new' AND 'create' both render the 'show' view, but I wouldn't want the new action to display the user's Quiz instance at that point because there would be no results to display. But I'm pretty sure I don't understand what you've written, sorry.

Comment: @moosefetcher I've just meant that after the `create` action you should render something: either the view of the newly created record by redirection to `show` action with the same view, or to redirect to a `new` action, in case you are creating a sequence of inctances of a model.

Comment: @moosefetcher sorry for the confuse, I've updated the answer with examples

Comment: It seems to be working, by either rendering the default 'create' view or adding `render :show`. It's updating the attributes of the Quiz instance APART FROM user_id, which I'll need later to check if a previous user has completed the quiz. Not sure why it's not updating that one attribute...